# How to define a method once, but have it as both class method and instance method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there any way to take an instance method and add it to the class (or vice versa)?

Here's my attempt, but it fails because Ruby doesn't let me bind an instance method to the class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

SOMETHING = :a
class SomeClass
  def some_method(variable, value)
    case SOMETHING
    when :c
      "output for case C"
    when :a, :b
      "output for A or B"
    end
  end
  # here's my failed attampt to add some_method to SomeClass:
  self.instance_method(:some_method).bind(self)
end

# it works as an instance method
bash = SomeClass.new
puts bash.some_method("EDITOR","vim")

# but not as a class method... yet
puts SomeClass.some_method("EDITOR","vim")
```

The error is "bind argument must be an instance of SomeClass". In other words, I can't call `bind(self)` because `self` *is* the class rather than an instance of the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a module and `include` and `extend` it your class with this method:

With `include` you define the instance method, with `extend` you define the class method.

MWE:

```
SOMETHING = :a

module SomeClassMeth
  def some_method(variable, value)
    case SOMETHING
    when :c
      "output for case C"
    when :a, :b
      "output for A or B"
    end
  end
end
class SomeClass
  include SomeClassMeth
  extend SomeClassMeth
end

# it works as an instance method
bash = SomeClass.new
puts bash.some_method("EDITOR","vim")

# but not as a class method... yet
puts SomeClass.some_method("EDITOR","vim")
```

But be careful, if you use attributes:

```
module SomeClassMeth
  def some_method(variable, value)
      @a
  end
end
class SomeClass
  @a = "@a in class"
  include SomeClassMeth
  extend SomeClassMeth

  def initialize
    @a = "@a in initialize"
  end

end

# it works as an instance method
bash = SomeClass.new
puts bash.some_method("EDITOR","vim")         #@a in initialize

# but not as a class method... yet
puts SomeClass.some_method("EDITOR","vim")  #@a in class
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better approach.  I should have thought of that.  Thanks.  I'll accept it as soon as SO's time limit is over.

Comment: @iconoclast you should wait some time, perhaps there is another better solution. (I have already a downvote for my answer (why? I'm willing to learn ;) ), maybe there is a problem with my solution). -- See also my update with a hint for possible problems.

Comment: iconoclast, if you remove `include SomeClassMeth` and insert `bash.extend SomeClassMeth` after `bash = SomeClass.new`, you will obtain identical output, but if you create a new instance `bash1`, `bash1.some_method("EDITOR","vim") => NoMethodError: undefined method`.  Here `extend` makes `some_method` a singleton method.  There may be no reason to do this here, but it is a technique that can sometimes be used to advantage.

Comment: +1 knut, you asked, "why?".  By now you should know that's rhetorical.  When was the last time you saw a downvoter leave an explanation?  I am in the camp that downvoters should state their reasons.